# Single label in Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas

I need to know if is possible to insert a label in the atlas that is different for any pages. If I add a new label, for example, a description, it will reported on every page of the atlas with the same text, but I need to insert different notes.
[image: This is one of the atlas page. In 'note' i need to add text that need to be different for each pages. But if I add a new label, it will the same in every pages.]

Comment: Are you talking about qgis atlas? If so add the tag please

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Could you provide an example image? Yes, it's possible. The workflow differs depending on your task. You could save the text directly in your atlaslayer or maybe via filepaths to html files

Comment: If you mean the text in text box, you can write an expression and refer to variables or attribute values on given feature. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Ok, thanks.  i will insert the information in a new attribute value in the table.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, you can fill any label or textbox in the composer with an expression based on attribute values.

The easiest way would be to add a fitting column in your coverage layer which is holding your notes. *(Fig. 1)*

[image]

In the composer, add a textbox/label, enter some static text and hit 'Insert an expression...'

The expression editor will open. Under 'Fields and values' you can double click any column to add its value (fig. 2), based on your current coverage feature, at the cursor position (fig. 3).

[image]

[image]

There are other ways of achieving more complex auto-filling tasks.

Example: For notes longer than 250 characters, you could add additional columns and concatenate them with an expression like:
concat( "Note1" , ' ' , "Note2" )

Comment: If this is a fitting solution for your task pls accept my answer ;) thank you